# How to add a sample Button inside Ribbon in ms dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm new to CRM , now i just want to add a sample button named as sample in Ribbon, i have exported "customized XML" ,  from here how to add custom id , command id etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of walkthroughs which should be able to help you with this:

- [this one](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/01/18/how-to-view-ribbon-definitions-in-crm-2011-3/)
- [this one](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/adding-my-first-custom-button-in-crm-2011/)
- and [this one](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/06/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-adding-and-removing-buttons-from-the-ribbon/)

There are also tools like this one on [CodePlex](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) which can help you do it in a graphical fashion rather than messing with the XML.

*Warning, opinion ahead*

I remember when I was new to Dynamics CRM that what helped me initially was working with tools from the community until I got my head around things and could dive into more of the guts of the platform. It might be worth going through a listing like [this](http://everythingcrm.net/2012/08/16/revised-list-of-useful-dynamics-crm-2011-tools-utilities-scripts-controls/) to see if there are things that can help you on your CRM journey.

Comment: Thnx @nkvu it helps a lot...:)

Comment: Hi nkvu , i followed ur second link , 
http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/adding-my-first-custom-button-in-crm-2011/

I imported only the final definition from that page ,  but while importing i get a error saying ,
"An error occured {1}{0} , so how to overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean by only imported the final definition? Most of the [time](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/2550ac2f-83df-4117-ac0e-8b34a860fe72/) this will be related to an error in customizations.xml or what you are trying to import....Are you putting the XML file back into the zipped solution and importing that? Have you tried any of the other links - the first one is probably the most comprehensive so you might want to try exporting your solution again and following the instructions there